# How to pass extra post value in fb.api function

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Please see this below code :

```
    FB.api(
    '/me/<namespace>:<action_type>',
    'post',
    {<object>:url},
    function(response) {

      //alert(response.responseText);
      console.log(response);

       if (!response || response.error) {
          alert('Error occured');
       } else {
          alert('latest was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
       }
```

Now suppose I have a url : http://domainname.com?getvar=somevalue. When I use this URL, getvar not generated on page because I am using  'Post' in Fb.api. Actually I have to use 'Post' only and I want to pass extra value with URL by using post method. How I can do this. Please let me know if you have any idea.

=================================================================================

I AM GOING TO EXPLAIN MY QUESTION ONCE AGAIN :

I am using open graph facebook api. I need to display some my website activities on FB timeline. I have done this for one of few actions like when I upload videos , it will appear on my facebook account. Now I also need to do same when somebody follows the user , it should also appear in FB timelines or log activity.

My problem start with meta tags :

```
       <meta name="ogtype" property="og:type" content="namespace:video"/>
```

Above meta tag I used for upload video action.

For next action when someone follow user, Then I have to use this below meta tag :

```
      <meta name="ogtype" property="og:type" content="namespace:user"/>
```

I have to do both on same page but there can be only one "ogtype" meta tag. So I decided to change dynamically ogtype meta tag.

In nutshell:

- Can I use any alternate way to use ogtype for fb.api action..?
- How I can use open graph more then one activity or action type..?

Thanks,

Comment: Not really clear what your problem is here. That you post the value to the API has nothing to do with it. If the URL is not the real canocial URL of your object, then its only natural the parameter gets lost if the Facebook scraper follows your real og:url value for that object.

Comment: Actually Fb.api use values from meta tags like e.g:                <meta name="ogtype" property="og:type" content=<namespace> : <object> >  I need to change og:type value dynamically.I was looking for an alternate to pass these value with fb.api call . In brief what is the way to send extra value with URL by post method (which is using in 4th line of above code). extra value can be also og:type. I hope you are getting my question.

Comment: The post is unrelated to the object url - the post simply states that you are performing a *write* operation on the Graph.